# Extract on history row last status

Tags: mysql

I have on MySQL database the table `tableStatus` with 76869 rows.

These 76869 rows are the history for each `element` and `Code node`.

On the history the single `element` and `Code node`could change his `status` and pass from `status` **AVAILABLE** to **UNAVAILABLE** and the other way around.

This is an example :

```
mysql> SELECT
    sis,
    element,
    `Code node`,
    MAX(Datetime),
    Status
FROM
    `tableStatus`
GROUP BY
    element,
    Status
ORDER BY
    MAX(Datetime) DESC;
+------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+
| sis  | element           | Code node     | MAX(Datetime)       | Status           |
+------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+
| 7605 | ZZ190923:TT214364 | 7605-2-190923 | 2019-01-22 09:02:47 | AVAILABLE        |
| 7604 | ZZ190923:ZZ394525 | 7605-2-190923 | 2019-01-22 09:02:43 | AVAILABLE        |
| 7145 | ZZ073097:TT070936 | 7605-2-190923 | 2018-12-19 15:16:23 | UNAVAILABLE      |
| 7144 | ZZ073097:ZZ072998 | 7605-2-190923 | 2018-12-19 15:16:20 | UNAVAILABLE      |
+------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+
4 rows in set
```

I need extract last position status only when the `status` is **UNAVAILABLE**  for each `element` and `Code node`.

I have tried with **WHERE** `status` is **UNAVAILABLE** but the output is wrong because last position of `status` in `Code node` '7605-2-190923' is **AVAILABLE** and should not be extracted.

```
mysql> SELECT
    sis,
    element,
    `Code node`,
    MAX(Datetime),
    Status
FROM
    `tableStatus`
WHERE
    `Code node` IN ('7605-2-190923')
AND Status IN ('UNAVAILABLE')
GROUP BY
    element,
    Status
ORDER BY
    MAX(Datetime) DESC;
+------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+
| sis  | element           | Code node     | MAX(Datetime)       | Status           |
+------+--- ---------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+
| 7145 | ZZ073097:TT070936 | 7605-2-190923 | 2018-12-19 15:16:23 | UNAVAILABLE      |
| 7144 | ZZ073097:ZZ072998 | 7605-2-190923 | 2018-12-19 15:16:20 | UNAVAILABLE      |
+------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+
2 rows in set
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `tableStatus` A
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        `Code node`, MAX(Datetime) LastDatetimeForNode
    FROM
        tableStatus
    GROUP BY `Code node`
    ) B ON A.`Code node` = B.`Code node` AND A.`Datetime` = B.`LastDatetimeForNode`
WHERE A.`Status` = 'UNAVAILABLE'
;
```

Comment: @Golia I see, I could help more if you could edit your post to have the result of  `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableStatus;`.

Comment: I'm sorry Nae, but I think that the output generated by your query is correct when filtering by `tableStatus.Code node IN ('7605-2-190923')` because this `Code node 7605-2-190923`  is **AVAILABLE** and should not be extracted... for this the output is empty ... do you agree ?

Comment: @Golia I am unable to comment on that as I can't see the entire data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    sis,
    element,
    t.`Code node`,
    Max_datetime,
    MAX(DATETIME) AS Mdt,
    STATUS
FROM
    `tableStatus` JOIN
  (SELECT `Code node`, MAX(DATETIME) AS 'Max_datetime'
     FROM `tableStatus`
     GROUP BY `Code node`) t
ON `tableStatus`.`Code node`=t.`Code node`
WHERE
    tableStatus.`Code node` IN ('7605-2-190923')
AND STATUS IN ('UNAVAILABLE')
GROUP BY
    element,
    STATUS
HAVING mdt=Max_datetime
ORDER BY
    MAX(DATETIME) DESC;
```

Comment: Many thanks for help but I have error `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'Max_datetime' in 'having clause'`

Comment: Sorry @Golia, I removed that column from `SELECT`.. because `HAVING` require the column to be present at the `SELECT` section. I've added the column back in the answer. You can try again ;)